# Error: Path contains forbidden segment '..' in meteor 1.4.4

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to access a template file outside working repository from parent directory.
added like:

```js
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.use(['templating', 'iron:router'], 'client');
  api.addFiles(['../../../xxx/xxx/x/abc.html'],'client',{isImport: true});
});
```

but getting below error:

```
Path contains forbidden segment '..'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show some brief overview of your folder structure? Otherwise it is hard to guess what you are trying to achieve